# is it possible to run multitouch Flash (AS3) Apps on Microsoft PixelSense (formerly Surface) Table?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pixelsense

I'd like to develop a simple multitouch game for a Microsoft PixelSense (formerly Surface) table. So my question is if it's possible to use Flash (ActionScript 3) to create the game or if I have to learn the PixelSense SDK and use Visual Studio - which would cost a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Yes, it's possible ;) With the Multitouch capabilities of Flash it's possible to develop for the PixelSense table.