# How is it possible to run multitouch Flash (AS3) Apps on Microsoft PixelSense (formerly Surface) Table?

Tags: flash, multi-touch, surface

I know there is already a question which ask if it is possible. but this question doesn't tell how it is possible. I need to use flash to make an application with multitouch on a Microsoft Surface table. I can't find it on google, and because I have no right to post comments. So I couldn't ask it in this topic: [is it possible to run multitouch Flash (AS3) Apps on Microsoft PixelSense (formerly Surface) Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931463/is-it-possible-to-run-multitouch-flash-as3-apps-on-microsoft-pixelsense-forme)